# Weighting mysql full-text search results by date

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using innodb full-text search to return a set of results where the newest posts are more relevant.  Just wanted to check that this the best method:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH(note) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE))/SQRT(GREATEST(1, DATEDIFF(NOW(), date))) AS score FROM notes WHERE userid = '$userid' HAVING score > 0 ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

A few "small" comments.

1. Don't use `SELECT *` for reasons outlined in this question's answers:

   [What is the reason to not use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)
2. Linebreaks and indentation make your code **much** easier to read:

   ```
   SELECT *, (MATCH(note) AGAINST (
       '$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE))/SQRT(GREATEST(1, DATEDIFF(NOW(), date)
       )) AS score 
   FROM notes 
   WHERE userid = '$userid' 
   HAVING score > 0 
   ORDER BY score DESC
   ```

Things I like:

- You're not writing it **ALL IN SHOUT-CASE** ;)